# How do I kill all screens?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen, kill

I accidentally created over 1000 screens. How do I kill them all with one command? (Or a few)

Comment: run --> `screen -ls | grep Detached | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill`

Comment: Good idea @sactiw.  I modified it to work with my named sessions, and tweaked the commands a bit for preference, cleaning the sessions out completely in case they are 'stuck' like they were for me, and listing again for the user as a sanity check: `screen -ls | grep "<name>" | cut -d. -f1 | tr --delete "\t" | xargs kill -9; screen -wipe; screen -ls;`

Comment: How did you accidentally create 1000 screens?

Comment: @duhaime asking the real question.

Comment: I was using a loop and running different parameters for a model in each screen. It all happened so fast!

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You can use :

```
pkill screen
```

Or

```
killall screen
```

---

In OSX the process is called SCREEN in all caps. So, use:

```
pkill SCREEN
```

Or

```
killall SCREEN
```

Comment: It's not recommended to use SIGKILL in this case. SIGTERM would be a much better choice.

Comment: Hi, Rahul Patil. why screen is not listed in `Top`

Comment: What if I don't have permissions? Do I have to manually go into and exit all the screens individually?

Comment: In OSX (also potentially in Linux), ongoing processes running inside the screen are "orphaned".

Answer (score 18):

If the screens are dead, use:

```
screen -wipe
```

Answer (score 13):

Have recently begun to familiarize myself with awk I put together this and it served its purpose. I posted it since its quite easy to understand.

`screen -ls | grep '(Detached)' | awk 'sys {screen -S $1 -X quit}'`

Where `screen -ls` lists all current screens.
`grep 'pattern'` filters out all matching rows. We can then get a handle for all detached screens and with `awk sys {command}` we can copy and paste together a command and execute it with `sys`, `$1` refers to the first argument picked up by awk. Finally we execute the quit command with `screen -X quit`.

Comment: ```screen -ls | grep '(Detached)' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I % -t screen -X -S % quit```

worked better for me.

Answer (score 7):

```
str=$(screen -ls)  

array=$(echo $str|tr "." "\n")  

for V in $array  
do  
if [ $V -gt 0  ]  
        then screen -S $V -X quit  
fi  
done
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for scr in $(screen -ls | awk '{print $1}'); do screen -S $scr -X kill; done
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit puzzled over how you managed to create 1000 "screens". Did you perhaps mean 1000 screen windows (1000 different terminal windows within a single screen session)?

If you meant 1000 windows within a single screen session, then a more elegant solution would be to quit screen using the command `C-a \` (ctrl-a followed by \).

Comment: Try executing screen 1000x within screen. What happens? You get 1000 screen windows. Yes, that's right, screen intelligently and mercifully doesn't spawn 1000 screen sessions. So if the OP had already started screen it should be far easier to accidentally start 1000 screen windows than to start 1000 screen sessions.

Comment: Strange but the comment I was replying to appears to have disappeared. Anyway I'm letting the above comment stand for the record.

Comment: Well it's actually pretty simple. Just make a infinite loop (by accident) and put something like this in there `screen -m sleep 100000`. This happened and I did not notice until it had already created over 1000 screen sessions.

Comment: How exactly does one create an infinite loop by accident?

Answer (score 1):

The following command will terminate all inactive screens:

```
perl -e 'while (map { kill 9, [split /\./]->[0] } grep { /Detached/ } split /\n/, qx{screen -ls}) { sleep 1 } exec qw(screen -wipe)'
```

Comment: This one works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the screen command itself to list all active screen sessions and then kill them one by one. Here's an example:

```
screen -ls | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I{} screen -X -S {} quit
```

This will list all active screen sessions using the `screen -ls` command, extract the session IDs using `awk`, and then pass each session ID to the `screen -X -S` command to quit the session.